# Git: Unable to clean working copy after refactoring file names

Tags: java, android, git, unix, refactoring

I somehow cause git to get all confused after renaming a directory in a Java project.  There are now a whole bunch of phantom files sitting in my working copy for the old file name that I can't seem to remove.

An example of one these changes is:

Example Diff: NumberUtils.java

`-package com.RedactedCompanyName.Helpers;
 +package com.RedactedCompanyName.helpers;`

Its basically just committing the location change.  But every time I try to commit this change, git (and source tree) just ignores it and they remain as uncommitted modifications

I've tried all the various git suggestions around StackOverflow:

`git reset --head head
git clean -rf`

None of them seem to work.

Even resetting to previous commit before this refactor, doing it properly and then merging back won't work because this file corruption is preventing a merge.

I even tried a 'scored earth' approach as well where I just cloned a new local copy of the repo.  The second I made my first commit, this noise re-appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you have to use [`git mv`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv) when you rename your classes (because the standard tools don't typically know to do that when renaming/refactoring Java files). If you can't do that, then you'll have to use [`git rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) to remove the old files.

For example,

```
git mv OldNumberUtils.java NumberUtils.java
git commit -m "Renamed OldNumberUtils to NumberUtils"
```

**or**, in your case (because `git` doesn't know about the rename)

```
git rm OldNumberUtils.java
git commit -m "Removing OldNumberUtils, because it was renamed NumberUtils"
```

Comment: That worked!  I guess the moral of the story is don't remain folder names in Java project unless you really have a good reason